# The first icon on my navigation bar is blue and larger than the others, how do I change that?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Completely new user of Android Studio is here, and I'm trying to make a movie review application as a school project.

So the problem here is that there will be several icons on my homepage's navigation bar, but the first icon for some reason is always blue and larger than the other icons, and I have no idea how to fix that, as you can see in the picture. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BGqH.jpg)

Here's the XML of my homepage.xml and the nav_items.xml

***HOMEPAGE***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".Homepage">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nav_items.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_input_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_list" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_home_black_24"
        android:title="@string/nav_home" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I think it is a behaviour on BottomNavigationBar since the selected one get highlighted, check the other one and see if it changes to the same behaviour

Comment: that's not a problem, it's a feature

Answer (score 1):

If it is blue by default then it means it is selected.

Comment: Are you able to give more information? If it is blue because it is selected, how could its size or colour be changed by the developer?